# Function to find out children of multiple HTML elements and use as custom attribute

Tags: javascript, html, dataset, children, custom-data-attribute

So I have the following structure with multiple `<div>` elements where I want to display the children inside each of it in a data attribute (`data-children`). Instead of manually changing the attribute, I'd like it to be dynamic with JS so it changes when I add/delete children elements.

```
<h2 class="amount_title" data-children="1">
  The amount of children of this element is
</h2>

<div class="parent_container">
  <div class="children_element">
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
</div>

<h2 class="amount_title" data-children="2">
  The amount of children of this element is
</h2>

<div class="parent_container">
  <div class="children_element">
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="children_element">
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

So right now I'm doing the following to get each element's children and populate the `data-attribute` of each title:

```
const parentContainer = document.querySelectorAll('.parent_container')
const amountTitle = document.querySelectorAll('.amount_title')

let childrenAmount1 = parentContainer[0].childElementCount
amountTitle[0].dataset.children = childrenAmount1

let childrenAmount2 = parentContainer[1].childElementCount
amountTitle[1].dataset.children = childrenAmount2
```

I have a few of these so it's obviously not ideal. Which function could help me to go through all of them and populate each dataset accordingly with the amount of children for each element? Thank you.

I tried to do a for () loop but all the datasets grabbed the amount of children from the last item in the array

Comment: What are the conventions for the namings? By what rules are the names chosen?

Comment: If you post the `for` loop you wrote, someone might be able to help you fix it.

Comment: well the for loop I used was this:

 for (let childrenAmount of parentContainer) {
      let totalChildren = childrenAmount.childElementCount;
      for (let titles of amountTitle) {
         titles.dataset.children = totalChildren;
      }
}

Comment: @tacoshy ... A good approach/implementation does neither depend on tag-/class-names nor on a given markup structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this configuration, your best strategy is to get the next element after each title. **Although I would recommend a wrapper** to set the title based on each wrapper contents `.wrapper > amount_title|parent_container` to loop through all wrappers first and get its children from the wrapper reference

```js
const titles = document.querySelectorAll(".amount_title");
titles.forEach((title) => {
  const next = title.nextElementSibling;
  if (!next.classList.contains("parent_container")) { return false; } // killswitch
  title.innerHTML = `The amount of children of this element is ${ next.childElementCount }`;
});
```

```html
<h2 class="amount_title" data-children="1">The amount of children of this element is </h2>
<div class="parent_container">
    <div class="children_element">
        <div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
        <button>Button</button>
    </div>
</div>

<h2 class="amount_title" data-children="2">The amount of children of this element is </h2>
<div class="parent_container">
    <div class="children_element">
        <div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
        <button>Button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="children_element">
        <div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
        <button>Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

*Edit:*
The wrapper method:

This method allows to move any element inside without caring about the order of the elements. When the other method works, this one allows you to set the title before or after the contents without breaking

```js
const wrappers = document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper");
wrappers.forEach((wrapper) => {
  const title = wrapper.querySelector(".amount_title");
  const contents = wrapper.querySelector(".parent_container");
  if (!title || !contents) { return; } // killswitch
  title.innerText = `The amount of children of this element is ${ contents.childElementCount }`
});
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h2 class="amount_title" data-children="1">The amount of children of this element is </h2>
  <div class="parent_container">
      <div class="children_element">
          <div>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          </div>
          <button>Button</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <h2 class="amount_title" data-children="2">The amount of children of this element is </h2>
  <div class="parent_container">
      <div class="children_element">
          <div>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          </div>
          <button>Button</button>
      </div>
      <div class="children_element">
          <div>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          </div>
          <button>Button</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply select all Headlines and use a `forEach` loop to loop through all those headlines. Then select the next sibling and count all elements that has the class `child_element` within:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', getAmountTitles);

function getAmountTitles() {
  // selects all h2 headliens with the amount_title class
  const HEADLINES = document.querySelectorAll('h2.amount_title');
  
  // forEach loop to iterate
  HEADLINES.forEach(headline => {
    // selects the enxt Sibling element (parent_container)
    let parent_container = headline.nextElementSibling;
    
    // gets the amount of child elements with the class children_element
    let amountChildElements = countChildrenElements(parent_container);
    
    // adds the data attribtue with the amount
    headline.dataset.children = amountChildElements;
    
    // adds the text to the headlines with the number
    headline.insertAdjacentText('beforeend', amountChildElements);
  });
}

function countChildrenElements(parentElement) {
  return (parentElement.querySelectorAll('.children_element').length);
}
```

```html
<h2 class="amount_title">The amount of children of this element is </h2>

<div class="parent_container">
  <div class="children_element">
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
</div>

<h2 class="amount_title">The amount of children of this element is </h2>

<div class="parent_container">
  <div class="children_element">
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="children_element">
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the header (`h2.amount_title`) is always directly before `div.parent_container` you can use `previousElementSibling` to give `[data-children]` its value. The snippet uses css to display the amount of child elements.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(`.parent_container`)
  .forEach(container => {
    container.previousElementSibling
      .dataset.children = container.childElementCount;
  });
```

```css
.amount_title:after {
  content: attr(data-children);
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="amount_title" data-children="1">The amount of children of this element is </h2>
<div class="parent_container">
  <div class="children_element">
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
</div>

<h2 class="amount_title" data-children="2">The amount of children of this element is </h2>
<div class="parent_container">
  <div class="children_element">
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="children_element">
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

When there may be elements between `h2.amount_title` and `div.parent_container` its better to wrap the elements within a div.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(`.parent_container`)
  .forEach(container => {
    container.closest(`.item`).querySelector(`.amount_title`)
      .dataset.children = container.childElementCount;
  });
```

```css
.amount_title:after {
  content: attr(data-children);
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <h2 class="amount_title" data-children="1">The amount of children of this element is </h2>
  <div class="parent_container">
    <div class="children_element">
      <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
      <button>Button</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <h2 class="amount_title" data-children="2">The amount of children of this element is </h2>
  <h3>**Container starts in next div</h3>
  <div class="parent_container">
    <div class="children_element">
      <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
      <button>Button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="children_element">
      <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
      <button>Button</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *is* and *has* selectors with the adjacent sibling combinator `+` to get just the *.amount_title* elements that have *.parent_container* as an adjacent sibling.

It then loops over them to update their data-children attribute and textContent. It doesn't visit any *.amount_title* element that doesn't have a *.parent_container* as an adjacent sibling, so `.nextElementSibling` should always return a *.parent_container* element.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  // Select all .amount_title elements with a following
  // .parent_container sibling
  document.querySelectorAll(':is(.amount_title):has(+ .parent_container)')
    // For each such element, get the next element sibling's count
    // of .children_elements and do updates
    .forEach(h => {
      let count = h.nextElementSibling.querySelectorAll('.children_element').length;
      h.textContent += count;
      h.dataset.children = count;
    }
  );
};

console.log(document.querySelectorAll(':is(.amount_title):has(+ .parent_container)').length);
```

```html
<h2 class="amount_title" data-children="">The amount of children of this element is </h2>

<div class="parent_container">
  <div class="children_element">
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
</div>

<h2 class="amount_title" data-children="">No .parent_container: </h2>

<h2 class="amount_title" data-children="">No .children_element: </h2>
<div class="parent_container"></div>


<h2 class="amount_title" data-children="">The amount of children of this element is </h2>

<div class="parent_container">
  <div class="children_element">
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="children_element">
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the OP already does make use of a [`data-*` global attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) like `data-children`, the OP might think about a generic implementation of displaying/updating child-count changes which will be fully agnostic to DOM structures, thus it always is going to work, regardless of chosen tag-names, class-names and nesting of markup structures.

One, for instance, could take inspiration from the [HTML `for` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/for). Just the minimum set of related `data-*` attributes like ...

```html
<tagName
  data-child-count="2"
  data-child-count-for="23fd215b-4c2a-4861-b53a-5c517e67a56e"
>
  The amount of children of the next element is 2.
</tagName>
```

... and ...

```html
<tagName data-child-count-id="23fd215b-4c2a-4861-b53a-5c517e67a56e">
  <!--
    ... any child structure like ...
  -->
  <tagName></tagName>
  <tagName></tagName>
</tagName>
```

... already enables a fully generic implementation of displaying/updating child-count changes.

For instance `[data-child-count-for="23fd215b-4c2a-4861-b53a-5c517e67a56e"]` marks an element which has to display/update a child-count change. The element's related `dataset.childCountFor`-value does identify the element where the child-count change is expected to happen. It is the very element which was marked by e.g. `[data-child-count-id="23fd215b-4c2a-4861-b53a-5c517e67a56e"]`.

The next provided example code shows how the function, the OP is looking for, would work upon such a generic markup.

```js
function updateChildCount(childCountNode) {
  const parentId = childCountNode.dataset.childCountFor;
  const parentNode =  document
    .querySelector(`[data-child-count-id="${ parentId ?? '' }"]`);

  if (parentNode) {
    const childCount = parentNode.childElementCount;

    childCountNode.dataset.childCount = childCount;
    childCountNode.textContent =
      `The amount of children of the next element is ${ childCount }.`;
  }
}
function updateAnyChildCount() {
  document
    .querySelectorAll('[data-child-count-for]')
    .forEach(updateChildCount);
}

// (re)render initial child-count values.
updateAnyChildCount();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
p { margin: 4px 0; }
h2 { font-size: 1em; margin: 8px 0 4px 0; }
button[data-add],
button[data-delete] { float: right; margin-left: 2px; }
```

```html
<h2
  data-child-count="unknown"
  data-child-count-for="23fd215b-4c2a-4861-b53a-5c517e67a56e"
>
  The amount of children of the next element is unknown.
</h2>

<div data-child-count-id="23fd215b-4c2a-4861-b53a-5c517e67a56e">
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <button>Button</button>

    <button data-add>clone 'n append</button>
    <button data-delete>delete</button>
  </div>
</div>

<h2
  data-child-count="unknown"
  data-child-count-for="69e7b5bf-698f-4492-94a0-e48243fcf1f9"
>
  The amount of children of the next element is unknown.
</h2>

<div data-child-count-id="69e7b5bf-698f-4492-94a0-e48243fcf1f9">
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <button>Button</button>

    <button data-add>clone 'n append</button>
    <button data-delete>delete</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <button>Button</button>

    <button data-add>clone 'n append</button>
    <button data-delete>delete</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <button>Button</button>

    <button data-add>clone 'n append</button>
    <button data-delete>delete</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
// - example's helper functionality which is going to invoke
//   the child-count update-function.
document
  .addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {

    const button = target.closest('[data-add], [data-delete]');
    if (button) {

      // mutate the DOM.

      if (button.matches('[data-add]')) {
        const { parentNode } = button;

        parentNode
          .parentNode
          .appendChild(
            parentNode.cloneNode(true)
          );
      } else {
        button
          .parentNode
          .remove();
      }

      // invoke the child-count update-function.
      updateAnyChildCount();
    }
  });
</script>
```

The above implementation could even be changed to just updating the `data-child-count` attribute. And since the element which features said attribute does always carry the current child-count via this attribute's value, one could introduce an additional single css-rule as simple as ...

```
[data-child-count]:after {
  content: attr(data-child-count);
}
```

... in order to always assure an up-to-date UI as well.

The following, slightly changed, example code just proves the last statement.

```js
function updateChildCount(childCountNode) {
  const parentId = childCountNode.dataset.childCountFor;
  const parentNode =  document
    .querySelector(`[data-child-count-id="${ parentId ?? '' }"]`);

  if (parentNode) {
    childCountNode.dataset.childCount = parentNode.childElementCount;
  }
}
function updateAnyChildCount() {
  document
    .querySelectorAll('[data-child-count-for]')
    .forEach(updateChildCount);
}
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
p { margin: 4px 0; }
h2 { font-size: 1em; margin: 8px 0 4px 0; }
button[data-add],
button[data-delete] { float: right; margin-left: 2px; }

[data-child-count]:after {
  content: attr(data-child-count);
}
```

```html
<h2
  data-child-count="1"
  data-child-count-for="23fd215b-4c2a-4861-b53a-5c517e67a56e"
>
  The amount of children of the next element is
</h2>

<div data-child-count-id="23fd215b-4c2a-4861-b53a-5c517e67a56e">
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <button>Button</button>

    <button data-add>clone 'n append</button>
    <button data-delete>delete</button>
  </div>
</div>

<h2
  data-child-count="3"
  data-child-count-for="69e7b5bf-698f-4492-94a0-e48243fcf1f9"
>
  The next element's child-count is
</h2>

<div data-child-count-id="69e7b5bf-698f-4492-94a0-e48243fcf1f9">
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <button>Button</button>

    <button data-add>clone 'n append</button>
    <button data-delete>delete</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <button>Button</button>

    <button data-add>clone 'n append</button>
    <button data-delete>delete</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <button>Button</button>

    <button data-add>clone 'n append</button>
    <button data-delete>delete</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
// - example's helper functionality which is going to invoke
//   the child-count update-function.
document
  .addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {

    const button = target.closest('[data-add], [data-delete]');
    if (button) {

      // mutate the DOM.

      if (button.matches('[data-add]')) {
        const { parentNode } = button;

        parentNode
          .parentNode
          .appendChild(
            parentNode.cloneNode(true)
          );
      } else {
        button
          .parentNode
          .remove();
      }

      // invoke the child-count update-function.
      updateAnyChildCount();
    }
  });
</script>
```

In addition the OP should make use of [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) and [`MutationRecord`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationRecord) where the latter gets provided as an array of records to an observer's [callback/handler function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/MutationObserver#parameters).

As for the OP's use case, one just needs to have a look at/into both [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)'s of each record which are [`addedNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationRecord/addedNodes) and [`removedNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationRecord/removedNodes). A child-count change has happened whenever either of the node-list's carries at least a single element-reference.

The decision for `MutationObserver` enables a maximum generic implementation for it decouples the change-handling/management entirely from any code which would trigger DOM-mutations such as element-insertion and -deletion.

In order to not being forced to having to observe the entire DOM-tree one would make use of a component-like approach based on the already introduced/proposed `data-*` attributes in cooperation with an element's related [`dataset`-property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).

The next provided example code demonstrates how one would identify such a loosely coupled (markup and DOM -wise) component, and how one would create a mutation observer for each such component.

```js
function getChildCountCopy(template, count) {
  return template
    .replace(/\$\{\s*childCount\s*\}/g, count);
}
function renderChildCount(childCountNode, observedNode) {
  const childCount = observedNode.childElementCount;

  childCountNode.textContent = getChildCountCopy(
    childCountNode.dataset.childCountTemplate, childCount,
  );
  childCountNode.dataset.childCount = childCount;
}

function handleChildCountChangeForBoundNodes(
  records/*, observer,*/
) {
  const { childCountNode, observedNode } = this;

  records
    .forEach(record => {
      const { addedNodes, removedNodes } = record;

      if (addedNodes.length + removedNodes.length > 0) {

        renderChildCount(childCountNode, observedNode);
      }
    });
}
function initializeChildCountMutationObserver(
  childCountNode, observedNode,
) {
  const observer = new MutationObserver(
    handleChildCountChangeForBoundNodes
      .bind({
        childCountNode,
        observedNode,
      }),
  );
  observer
    .observe(observedNode, {
      childList: true,
      //  subtree: true,
      // attributes: true,
    });
}

function enableInstantChildCount(childCountNode) {
  const { childCountFor: observedId } = childCountNode.dataset;
  
  const observedNode = document
    .querySelector(`[data-child-count-id="${ observedId ?? '' }"]`);

  if (observedNode) {

    // (re)render initial/current child-count.
    renderChildCount(childCountNode, observedNode);

    // register handling of element related DOM mutations.
    initializeChildCountMutationObserver(
      childCountNode, observedNode,
    );
  }
}
document
  .querySelectorAll('[data-child-count-for]')
  .forEach(enableInstantChildCount);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
p { margin: 4px 0; }
h2 { font-size: 1em; margin: 8px 0 4px 0; }
button[data-add],
button[data-delete] { float: right; margin-left: 2px; }
```

```html
<h2
  data-child-count="1"
  data-child-count-for="23fd215b-4c2a-4861-b53a-5c517e67a56e"
  data-child-count-template="The amount of children of the next element is ${ childCount }."
>
  The amount of children of the next element is 1.
</h2>

<div data-child-count-id="23fd215b-4c2a-4861-b53a-5c517e67a56e">
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <button>Button</button>

    <button data-add>clone 'n append</button>
    <button data-delete>delete</button>
  </div>
</div>

<h2
  data-child-count-for="69e7b5bf-698f-4492-94a0-e48243fcf1f9"
  data-child-count-template="The next element's child-count is ${ childCount }."
>
  The next element's child-count is unknown.
</h2>

<div data-child-count-id="69e7b5bf-698f-4492-94a0-e48243fcf1f9">
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <button>Button</button>

    <button data-add>clone 'n append</button>
    <button data-delete>delete</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <button>Button</button>

    <button data-add>clone 'n append</button>
    <button data-delete>delete</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <button>Button</button>

    <button data-add>clone 'n append</button>
    <button data-delete>delete</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
// example's helper functionality which is going to trigger DOM mutations.
document
  .addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {

    const button = target.closest('[data-add], [data-delete]');
    if (button) {

      // mutate the DOM.

      if (button.matches('[data-add]')) {
        const { parentNode } = button;

        parentNode
          .parentNode
          .appendChild(
            parentNode.cloneNode(true)
          );
      } else {
        button
          .parentNode
          .remove();
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: @MarcosCuadros ... The OP might have a look into the late provided above solution which is based on an entirely generic approach which makes one not worry neither about the source of DOM-mutations nor about future markup changes (like tag-/css-names and markup nesting).